# JPA Entity gets saved to wrong database

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

i have an entity class which should get persisted in one of two databases, depending on an attribute of the object. I created two different JPA controller classes with different persistance units:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "DS_PU")
private EntityManager em;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MS_PU")
private EntityManager em;
```

The persistance units are defined in the persistance.xml file as following:

```
<!-- AUT -->
<persistence-unit name="DS_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/gammusmsd</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="300000"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="DS_package"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<!-- DE -->
<persistence-unit name="MS_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/gammusmsd_de</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="300000"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="MS_package"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The datasources are correctly configured in a Glassfish 3.1.2 instance.

I use following code to create and persist the object:

```
Outbox  outbox = new Outbox();
...
...

if (outbox.getDestinationNumber().startsWith("0049")) {
    _OutboxController1.create(outbox);
    _OutboxController1.flush();
    logger.info("1");
} else {
    _OutboxController2.create(outbox);
    _OutboxController2.flush();
    logger.info("2");
}
```

The if statement does the job, but all the objects are inserted into the database connected to the second `OutboxController`. Is it possible, that creating a object with `Outbox  outbox = new Outbox();` will automatically attach the object to the first database defined in the `persistance.xml` file? As i know, an object should just get attached when using the `persist()` method.

Edit:
Both classes `OutboxController1` and `OutboxController2` extend the abstract class `AbstractFacade`, where the created method is defined as following:

```java
try {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
} catch (EntityExistsException e) {
      try {
          getEntityManager().merge(entity);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
      }
}
```

Comment: Please, post the relevant code from the `_OutboxController1` and `_OutboxController2` classes. PS `new Outbox()` has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you're setting the outbox destination number to start with "0049"? From your problem it seems Your if condition is never true so I assume either this number is assigned wrong or your condition is wrong.

Comment: The if statement works because the right log message gets printed depending on the prefix of the String.

Comment: Debug and investigate, that your code realy trying to use correct `EntityManager` or correct `Controller`.

Comment: I would look at that getEntityManager() method for a possible source of where the wrong entity manager gets returned. There is not going to be any mystery; if the record gets persisted to the wrong database, it is being persisted through the wrong entity manager. Occam's Razor is your best friend.